# C# - Create new objects of 'interface-represented-classes' within a static class

Tags: c#, dll, plugins, interface

I have an application which I want to extend with a plugin functionality. I follow this approach:

[Creating a simple plugin mechanism](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-a-simple-plugin-b45f1d4e)

My application has a class Table and a static class TableManager which manages (add, get) the table objects. TableManager should stay a static class. To make it possible for plugin writers to access also all current table objects, I want to put the 'TableManager' and 'Table' in an own dll. I can't simply put the whole implementation of Table to the dll because of to much dependent code inside of Table. So I created an interface of Table within the dll and the class Table in my application implements this interface.

**'Table'-class in MainApplication:**

```cs
public class Table : ITable
{
    private string _name;
    public Table (string newName)
    {
       _name = newName;
    }
    // Here is much more code
}
```

**dll:**

```cs
public static class TableManager
{  
    private static Dictionary<string, ITable> _tableDict = new Dictionary<string, ITable>();
        
    public static Dictionary<string, ITable> getDict
    {
        get { return _tableDict; }
    }
        
    public static void addTable(string name)
    {
        // This is the line where the fault occurs:
        _tableDict[name] = new ITable(name);
    }
}


public interface ITable
{
    string name { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is now that I can't create new ITable-objects within TableManager like I did it until now with Table-objects, because I can't create new instances of an interface. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: You can not initiate instance of an interface. You need to implement interface in a class and initiate instance of that class. Does your code compile?

Comment: The code i posted is just an example and in this version like i posted it, it doesn't compile because of the error. Also my real code doesn't compile because of the fault message i get when i want to create the new ITable. Could you maybe post your a code example of your solution based on my above posted code?

Comment: 1. make sure that `Table` implements `ITable` (`public class Table
 : ITable`). 2. change `addTable` to `_tableDict[name] = new Table(name);`

Comment: Your first change is also implemented in my real code, just forget to add it here, sorry! (Updated it now) The second change is not possible, because in the dll-project, the normal 'Table'-class from my main application is not known. So i can't create a new instance of Table because i only know the interface within the dll-project.

Comment: "Someone" needs to know how to create a valid object of a concrete class that implements the interface. Look for "dependency injection" or "(abstract) factory pattern". If the DLL of `TableManager` mustn't know about the concrete `Table` class, then there must be a third library that "knows both" (and "is known by" `TableManager`) that basically tells `TableManager`: "if you need a new instance of something that implements `ITable`, just ask me, I know how to get that for you." --- or go down the road of reflection... but there be dragons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as [Corak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231655/c-sharp-create-new-objects-of-interface-represented-classes-within-a-static#comment77430201_45231655) mentioned in his comment, if you need to *somehow* create `Table` objects within `TableManager`, you need *someone* who knows about `Table` and is aware of how to construct it. In other words, you need a factory that can create an object represented to a client via `ITable` interface.

*How* you reach it is not that important - that can be a separate factory object, or a factory method within `ITable` interface.

Here's an example with a factory object:

### Addition to main application:

```
public class TableFactory : ITableFactory
{
    public ITable NewTable(string name)
    {
        return new Table(name);
    }
}
```

### Addition to dll:

```
public interface ITableFactory
{
    ITable NewTable(string name);
}

public class TableManager
{  
    private ITableFactory factory;

    public TableManager(ITableFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void addTable(string name)
    {
        _tableDict[name] = factory.NewTable(name);
    }

    /* the rest of your code */
}
```

See live sample [at Rextester](http://rextester.com/DURBT60741)

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in comment you can not create an instance of interface. You need to create a class implementing the interface.
Consider following code.

```
public interface ITable
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Table : ITable
{
    public Table(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
    public string Name {get;set;}
} 

public static class TableManager
{  
    private static Dictionary<string, ITable> _tableDict = new Dictionary<string, ITable>();

    public static Dictionary<string, ITable> getDict
    {
        get { return _tableDict; }
    }

    public static void addTable(string name)
    {
        _tableDict[name] = new Table(name);
    }
}
```

I hope this would help you resolve your issue.

Comment: Ah now i know what you mean. This is the way i had it before. But now i want to extract TableManager and Table into an own dll like shown in the example. This means also that the dll doesn't know the class 'Table'. Therefore i can't create a 'Table'-object within my dll. Or is there a way to make the 'Table'-class known for the dll without putting the whole implementation of 'Table' to the dll?

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit interface in class

```
  public class Table : ITable
```

and them inicialise Table class not ITable interface. You can not initiate interfaces.

Comment: Thank you! I just forget it in the example code here, in my real application it was implemented already. I edited the question now. ;)